# Basic non blocking tcp connect example for C

Tags: c, sockets, tcp, nonblocking

I am a having a hard time understanding blockless sockets and how I can use them for a network scanner. What I understand I should do is to set the socket to nonblocking with the following:

```
fcntl(sockfd , F_SETFL, O_NONBLOCK);
```

and then just call connect which should return EINPROGRESS.
Then after that I should use select like this:

```
if (select(sockfd  + 1, NULL, &fdset, NULL, &tv) == 1)
```

where tv is the adress of a timeval struct.

Then

```
getsockopt(sockfd , SOL_SOCKFD ET, SO_ERROR, &so_error, &len);
```

to know if the operation was successful or not, but it is always true.

Could somebody here give me an example of a tiny c program which 
checks if an ip is up or not, explaining the whole thing? 
I feel really clueless about how to do it.

Comment: ' Member since today' go back and read the site help, take the tour.

Comment: Keep calm and use sentences. Can you show a [minimal complete example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)?

Comment: do a google search for something like: `how to use a non-blocking socket in c`  This will bring up many examples for you to read/understand.  The fact that you are asking here indicates you did not put any effort into this.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`SO_ERROR` returns the socket's last error code and resets it. If `select()` reports the socket is writable, the connection was successful, no need to check the error code. If `select()` reports a timeout, the connection is still in progress so the error code will still be `EINPROGRESS`, just close the socket and move on. To detect a connection failure, put the socket into an `fd_set` in the `exceptfds` parameter of `select()`, and then check `SO_ERROR` only if that `fd_set` is still set when `select()` returns > 0.

```
fcntl(sockfd, F_SETFL, O_NONBLOCK);

res = connect(sockfd, ...);
if (res == -1)
{
    if (errno != EINPROGRESS)
    {
        // connect failed, do something...
        return;
    }

    fd_set wfd, efd;

    FD_ZERO(&wfd);
    FD_SET(sockfd, &wfd);

    FD_ZERO(&efd);
    FD_SET(sockfd, &efd);

    timeval tv;
    ...

    res = select(sockfd+1, NULL, &wfd, &efd, &tv);
    if (res == -1)
    {
        // select failed, do something...
        close(sockfd);
        return;
    }

    if (res == 0)
    {
        // connect timed out...
        close(sockfd);
        return;
    }

    if (FD_ISSET(sockfd, &efd))
    {
        // connect failed, do something...
        getsockopt(sockfd, SOL_SOCKET, SO_ERROR, &so_error, &len);
        close(sockfd);
        return;
    }
}

// connected !
```

Comment: For completeness, way back in the early 1990s before `SO_ERROR` the recommended technique was to call `connect()` again and check the `errno` if it still returned -1, after the socket became writeable.

Comment: @user207421 nobody needs to resort to that anymore.